# antlr4 failed to generate grammar

Tags: antlr4

The code `tool.process(grammar, false);` produces a null pointer exception.

See my code below:

```
package antlr;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import org.antlr.v4.Tool;
import org.antlr.v4.tool.Grammar;
import org.antlr.v4.tool.ast.GrammarRootAST;
import org.junit.Test;

// License : Apache License Version 2.0  https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
/**
 *
 * @author Peter <peter@quantr.hk>
 */
public class TestDynamicParser {

    @Test
    public void testDynamicParser() throws Exception {
        Tool tool = new Tool();
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(getClass().getResource("Hello.g4").toURI())));
        GrammarRootAST ast = tool.parseGrammarFromString(content);
        Grammar grammar = tool.createGrammar(ast);
        tool.process(grammar, false);
    }
}
```

Grammar:

```
grammar Hello;
r   : 'hello' ID;
ID  : [a-z]+ ;
WS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at antlr.TestDynamicParser.testDynamicParser(TestDynamicParser.java:23)
```

How can I prevent this error from occurring?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Is `content` null? Try it with `String content = "grammar Hello;\nr   : 'hello' ID;\nID  : [a-z]+ ;\nWS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;";`

Comment: no, content is not null

Comment: Which line is 23? By my count that is this line:

```
tool.process(grammar, false);
```

I'm not sure how tool could be null.

Comment: line 23 is tool.process(grammar, false);  , i have fixed it myself, please see https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/2362   . I am not sure why the code was working but just not now. Any hints? Anyway I have upgrade my netbenas-antlr plugin to correct code.